# mail - pop account crashes mail when it checks

Tags: mail.app, crash

I'm using osx mail with a pop account (need for my workflow).

Issue:

- when mail opens and checks the a specific pop account mail crashes.  It's only this specific account. Other pop accounts work.

Troubleshooting: that didn't work

- I have deleted and re-added the account. Which resolved the issue but after a few months the issue occurred again then i have to redownload all my messages again and sort through them to get back to where I was which is time consuming.
- ~/Library/Mail/V6/MailData removed "Envelope Index" to allow the reimport to occur again. issue still occurs
- Talked to the mail provider and everything checks out fine with the account
- have thunderbird configured but this issue doesn't occur on thunderbird (suspect osx mail client)

Question

- It seems like

Comment: suggestion: keep the Console.app open while launching Mail and check for the errors that happens in the system... could give a hint at what is really happening (my guess: a bad-formatted/too-big message - and yes, usually thunderbird is more resilient)

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. I think that might be another approach to troubleshoot it further.

Answer (score 1):

Ok the issue was that I sent an email using the pop account to itself and for some reason osx mail couldn't handle it and would keep crashing trying to download that email.   So I used my iPhone to access the mail through IMAP looked at the other emails from the last email that I received on my computer and process of elimination deleted those subsequent emails until i found the offending email.